# How to use "docker.io" containers in Ubuntu 14.04 with IPv6?

Tags: networking, 14.04, ipv6, docker

I'm trying this:

At the physical host with Ubuntu 14.04 (container's gateway for both IPv6 and IPv4), I tried:

```
root@docker-srv-1:~# ip -6 a a 2804:XXX:4:acbd::1/64 dev docker0
```

Of course, host docker-srv-1 can "ping6 google.com" and, the subnet 2804:XXX:4:abcd::/64 is routed to it. I can "ping6 2804:XXX:4:acbd::1" from anywhere is the World (Container's IPv6 gateway (docker0 interface)) right now.

Later, I'm planning to run the radvd directly on docker0 interface, so, the containers will auto-generate its own SLAAC IPv6 address automatically (I believe it will, if works statically first).

```
root@docker-srv-1:~# docker.io run -t -i tmartinx/ubuntu-14.04-server-cloudimg /bin/bash
```

But, within the container:

```
root@112c9071041a:/# ip -6 a a 2804:XXX:4:acbd::20/64 dev eth0
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

I also tried:

```
root@docker-srv-1:~# docker.io run --lxc-conf="lxc.network.ipv6=2804:XXX:4:acbd::20/64" --lxc-conf="lxc.network.ipv6.gateway=2804:XXX:4:acbd::1" -d -e lxc -t -i tmartinx/ubuntu-14.04-server-cloudimg /bin/bash 

235d2bea7d9b4cc54d08c6eb9e623e5655ac4e1668a9a7e255e796d254ce4845
2014/04/22 00:50:08 Error: Cannot start container 235d2bea7d9b4cc54d08c6eb9e623e5655ac4e1668a9a7e255e796d254ce4845: lxc.network.ipv6 = 2804:XXX:4:acbd::20/64 is not supported by the native driver
```

I found some tips here: http://zargony.com/2013/10/13/ipv6-in-docker-containers - But it didn't worked...    :'(

I also tried docker.io with "-d -e lxc" but, didn't worked with IPv6 either...

Am I missing something?!

---

EDITED #1:

Now I'm running docker.io with --privileged, like this:

```
docker.io run --privileged -t -i tmartinx/ubuntu-14.04-server-cloudimg /bin/bash
```

So, I can run "ip -6 a a $IPV6_ADDR" BUT, still can't ping6 its gateway (locally reachable docker0 int - IPv4 works) and, of course no IPv6 connectivity at all...

Source:

IPV6 address
 https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/4483

---

EDITED #2:

After researching a bit more, I did:

```
sudo apt-get install lxc
```

Added to /etc/default/docker.io the following line:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-d -e lxc"
```

Docker restarted but, still no IPv6... Anyway, the error message is now different, look:

```
root@docker-srv-1:~# docker.io run --lxc-conf="lxc.network.ipv6=2804:XXX:4:acbd::20/64" --lxc-conf="lxc.network.ipv6.gateway=2804:XXX:4:acbd::1" -t -i tmartinx/ubuntu-14.04-server-cloudimg /bin/bash
lxc-start: Cannot add ipv6 gateway for eth0 when not bringing up the interface
lxc-start: failed to setup netdev
lxc-start: failed to setup the network for '5c7d1765a7a93bff96711865ebd9325b9b9bf071e89c466fe1ae75a336af10f8'
lxc-start: failed to setup the container
lxc-start: invalid sequence number 1. expected 2
lxc-start: failed to spawn '5c7d1765a7a93bff96711865ebd9325b9b9bf071e89c466fe1ae75a336af10f8'
2014/04/22 04:58:25 Error: Cannot start container 5c7d1765a7a93bff96711865ebd9325b9b9bf071e89c466fe1ae75a336af10f8: exit status 1
```

---

EDITED #3

Docker with IPv6 is working now!!! What I did?

After installing `lxc` (EDITED #2) and reconfiguring DOCKER_OPTS to enable it, Docker with IPv6 is working with the following command:

```
docker.io run --privileged --lxc-conf="lxc.network.ipv6 = 2804:XXX:4:acbd::200/64" --lxc-conf="lxc.network.ipv6.gateway = 2804:XXX:4:acbd::1" --lxc-conf="lxc.network.flags = up" -t -i tmartinx/ubuntu-14.04-server-cloudimg /bin/bash
```

---

If someone else have a better solution, please, post it!

Thanks!

Thiago

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding this question! Can you please cut out the parts that are no longer necessary?

Comment: Jorge, thank you for your time! But, you guys can mark this as "solved". Please, ignore it. Since I'm already using docker.io with  IPv6 flawlessly.

Comment: @ThiagoCMC did you have to set `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1` or any other sysctl config for this? Did you have to configure `radvd`?

Comment: @kevzettler yes, I did it, look here: https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/pull/2974#issuecomment-42509038